# RntimeError for tensor size in mmsegmentation for freiburg forest dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to use different segmentation models to segment the freiburg forest dataset.
The link to the dataset is given below.

http://deepscene.cs.uni-freiburg.de/segment_random/CITYSCAPES_RGB?dataset=freiburgforest&model=FOREST_RGB

I have made the required config files for mmsegmentation according to the documentation in the link below.

https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmsegmentation/blob/0.x/docs/en/tutorials/config.md

I am getting the following error in the code. And I cannot backtrack this error to its source. Can someone please tell me exactly where the error is originating and how to fix it?

Following is the error message that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 105, in main
    runner.train()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1733, in train
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 278, in run
    self.run_iter(data_batch)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 301, in run_iter
    outputs = self.runner.model.train_step(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 121, in train_step
    losses = self._run_forward(data, mode='loss')
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 161, in _run_forward
    results = self(**data, mode=mode)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1040, in forward
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/train.py", line 109, in <module>
    output = self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1000, in _run_ddp_forward
    return module_to_run(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/base.py", line 94, in forward
    main()
  File "tools/train.py", line 105, in main
    return self.loss(inputs, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 177, in loss
    runner.train()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/runner.py", line 1733, in train
    loss_decode = self._decode_head_forward_train(x, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 138, in _decode_head_forward_train
    loss_decode = self.decode_head.loss(inputs, data_samples,
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 262, in loss
    losses = self.loss_by_feat(seg_logits, batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 324, in loss_by_feat
    loss[loss_decode.loss_name] = loss_decode(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    model = self.train_loop.run()  # type: ignore
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 278, in run
    self.run_iter(data_batch)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/runner/loops.py", line 301, in run_iter
    outputs = self.runner.model.train_step(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 121, in train_step
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/losses/cross_entropy_loss.py", line 271, in forward
    losses = self._run_forward(data, mode='loss')
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mmengine/model/wrappers/distributed.py", line 161, in _run_forward
    loss_cls = self.loss_weight * self.cls_criterion(
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/losses/cross_entropy_loss.py", line 45, in cross_entropy
    loss = F.cross_entropy(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3026, in cross_entropy
    results = self(**data, mode=mode)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1040, in forward
    output = self._run_ddp_forward(*inputs, **kwargs)
      File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/distributed.py", line 1000, in _run_ddp_forward
return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [2, 256, 256, 3]
    return module_to_run(*inputs[0], **kwargs[0])
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/base.py", line 94, in forward
    return self.loss(inputs, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 177, in loss
    loss_decode = self._decode_head_forward_train(x, data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/segmentors/encoder_decoder.py", line 138, in _decode_head_forward_train
    loss_decode = self.decode_head.loss(inputs, data_samples,
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 262, in loss
    losses = self.loss_by_feat(seg_logits, batch_data_samples)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/decode_heads/decode_head.py", line 324, in loss_by_feat
    loss[loss_decode.loss_name] = loss_decode(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1190, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/losses/cross_entropy_loss.py", line 271, in forward
    loss_cls = self.loss_weight * self.cls_criterion(
  File "/home/deshpand/Thesis/semantic_segmentation_network/mmseg_new/mmsegmentation/mmseg/models/losses/cross_entropy_loss.py", line 45, in cross_entropy
    loss = F.cross_entropy(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3026, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
RuntimeError: only batches of spatial targets supported (3D tensors) but got targets of size: : [2, 256, 256, 3]
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: 1) local_rank: 0 (pid: 1128219) of binary: /home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 195, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 191, in main
    launch(args)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launch.py", line 176, in launch
    run(args)
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 753, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 132, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/deshpand/anaconda3/envs/openmmlab/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 246, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError: 
============================================================
tools/train.py FAILED
------------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
[1]:
  time      : 2023-05-29_10:18:58
  host      : neptun.informatik.uni-kl.de
  rank      : 1 (local_rank: 1)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 1128220)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
------------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-05-29_10:18:58
  host      : neptun.informatik.uni-kl.de
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : 1 (pid: 1128219)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : To enable traceback see: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/elastic/errors.html
============================================================
```

Comment: You did not include the error message in the question.

Comment: my apologies. Updated the issue